# How to display data by current month and display no data message if data not exists

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I want to  show data by current month and show 'no data to display' message if no data exists on current month. I managed to show all data ascending by date, but this time I only want it to display the data by current month. Oh, I'm using Laravel & ChartJS.

Here is the data query on controller :

```
$achieveDaily = DailyProduction::orderBy('tgl', 'asc')->get();
```

Here is the foreach function to display data :

```
        foreach($achieveDaily as $ad){
          $labels1[] = Carbon::parse($ad->tgl)->format('j');
          $plan1[] = $ad->plan;
          $actual1[] = $ad->actual;
        };
```

And here is the chartjs script :

```
<script>

var labelsL1    = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($labels1) !!}');
var plan        = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($plan1) !!}');
var actual      = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($actual1) !!}');

const data = {
        labels: labelsL1,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Plan',
            data: plan,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8)',
            datalabels:{
                color: '#000000',
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'top'
            },
        },
        {
            label: 'Actual',
            data: actual,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
            datalabels:{
                color: '#000000',
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'top'
            },
        }]
    };

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('dailyAchieveChart');
const dailyAchieve1 = new Chart(
    ctx,
    config
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i already solved this by using if else condition, and then using isEmpty() to check if the collection is empty or not, if it's not empty, then run the foreach.  Like this :

```
        if($achieveDaily->isEmpty()){
        $labels1[] = [];
        $plan1[] = [];
        $actual1[] = [];
    }else{
        foreach($achieveDaily as $ad){
            $labels1[] = Carbon::parse($ad->tgl)->format('j');
            $plan1[] = $ad->plan;
            $actual1[] = $ad->actual;
        }
    };
```

Thank you for everyone who tried to help me! Appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use function whereMonth in laravel

```
DailyProduction::whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->get();
```

Comment: i did. and it returns "undefined variable $labels1". i suspected because of there's no data on current month, that's why laravel shows this error?

Comment: may be you can use if else for handle this issue

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to display data by current Month, can use `whereDate()` function. Why **NOT** combine `whereMonth()` and `whereYear()` together?

They will run separate query for just filtering specific month, and specific year and combine it.

So *better query = better performance*. Here's example :

```php
$dailyProduction = DailyProduction::whereDate('tgl', 'like', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m') . '%')->orderBy('tgl')->get();

$labels = [1, 2, ...]; // Basically anything to your graph labels, i assume you want to show daily
$plan = $actual = [];

foreach($dailyProduction as $daily) {
  $plan[] = $daily->plan;
  $actual[] = $daily->actual;
}
```

At your graph, when no data is there, just keep it blank. Or use blade `@if @else`

```php
@if(empty($dailyProduction))
   <p>No Data</p>
@else
   // Your Graph
@endif
```

At your `<script>`. I assume rest of your const `data` is right

```
var labelsL1    = {!! json_encode($labels) !!};
var plan        = {!! json_encode($plan) !!};
var actual      = {!! json_encode($actual) !!};
```

Comment: i tried this and i get "compact(): Undefined variable $labels1" error. can you help me with that?

Comment: keep the foreach, u need it to display data. since $labels1 is from foreach

Comment: okay, so, i suspect that the error i get because there is no data on current month, right? if so, how to solve it? i mean, how to display no data message, because i place the foreach in controller, not in blade like usual? (i'm still new at Laravel so i'm quite confused with this)

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: still get the same error using the edited answer

Comment: show your errors, can from edit your question or just throw link to view your errors

Comment: Hi, here's the link to the errors : https://paste.pics/GWBI7

Comment: sorry for late reply, if you try to dd($labels1) and no result, u need to declare $labels1 first before foreach loop. hope it helps. compact() error means laravel dont know what's $labels1 is, so declare before foreach may fixed it

Comment: i did declare the $labels1 as array() before loop, it works, but it doesn't show the data from database when i looped it, it only shows empty data.

Comment: hi! i think i already solved this. i'm using isEmpty() inside if else condition to check if the data is empty, else run the foreach. and it worked.